# How to get the user_money value from the database so that it is output with the /money command?

Tags: sqlite

How do I get the user_money value from the SQLite database and output it with the /money command?
it is necessary that when entering the /money command, the value from the sqlite database is output. How to implement it? I write in python, pyTelegramBotAPI.

````
import telebot
import sqlite3

bot = telebot.TeleBot('5107117113:AAFKBPtDjw_ZCNn7agSUhIfHSXal5vN_dds')


@bot.message_handler(commands=['start'])
def start(message):
    connect = sqlite3.connect('users.db')
    cursor = connect.cursor()
    cursor.execute("""CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS login_id(
        id INTEGER, money INTEGER
    )""")
    connect.commit()
    people_id = message.chat.id
    cursor.execute(f"SELECT id FROM login_id WHERE id = {people_id}")
    data = cursor.fetchone()

    if data is None:
        user_id = message.chat.id
        user_money = '10000'
        cursor.execute("INSERT INTO login_id VALUES(?, ?);", (user_id, user_money))
        connect.commit()
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Вы успешно зарегестрирован. Ваш баланс: 10000 рублей.')
    else:
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Вы уже в базе')



@bot.message_handler(commands=['money'])
def money(message):
    connect = sqlite3.connect('users.db')
    cursor = connect.cursor()
    user_money = cursor.fetchall()
    people_id = message.chat.id
    cursor.execute(f"SELECT user_money FROM login_id WHERE id = {people_id}")
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Ваше бабло:', user_money)

bot.polling()
```[enter image description here][1]


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/esVHk.jpg
````

Answer (score 0):

bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Ваше бабло:', **{**user_money**}**)

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).